# How to move and install a .DLL as an Active X addon for Internet Explorer on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, dll, activex

In Internet Explorer  `Tools > Manage add-ons`, my workstation has `PEDUServiceFunctions.dll` as an ActiveX Control addon.

I want to move this addon to another workstation, so my attempt has been to run `regsvr32 -i PEDUServiceFunctions.dll` on the target, resulting in the error message:

[image]

I don't have any .OCX file, which some people suggest to use with `regsrv32` on Google.

How can I install `PEDUServiceFunctions.dll` as an ActiveX Control addon on the target workstation?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the installer for the add-on to do this?

Comment: I don't have it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly indicates that the DLL is **not** ActiveX,
by the fact that it doesn't export `DllRegisterServer`.

The ActiveX add-on you lost must have included more than one DLL.
In other words, you are missing the crucial DLL that is the main part
of this ActiveX add-on.

The name `PEDUServiceFunctions` also indicates that this DLL contains
functions that are used to service some other part of the ActiveX.

So, unfortunately, you absolutely need that missing DLL or (more likely) OCX.